# Cytoscape - Name Column Empty - Needed for Selecting Nodes with ID List

Tags: cytoscape

I have imported a network to Cytoscape, and under the list of 'Nodes' there is detail in a column called 'Shared Name' but nothing under the column 'Name'.

I want to Select nodes based on a list of IDs. When I tried at first, nothing happened. When I copied a few of the names into the 'Name' column, it then did work (I believe this is the column it refers to when you select by IDs).

However, I'm trying to select 300 nodes, so don't want to go through and copy and paste each 'Shared Name' into 'Name'. Is there an easy way to copy and paste the whole column? Or is there a way to select nodes using IDs and refer to the Shared Names column instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were able to import a network without a name column.  On initial import, the name and shared name columns should be the same.  In any case, you could just add an equation to the name column that sets everything to the shared name column.

To do this, click on a cell in the Name column, click on the formula button "f(x)", and just select "shared name" from the list of columns, then click insert.  Set it to "Apply to: " entire column, and then "Evaluate and insert result".  Now, your "Name" column is a duplicate of your "Shared name" column.